# Microsoft office web app(OWA) server 2013 installation issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, owa, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to use Microsoft office webapps server 2013(OWA) with my sharepoint 2013.Although I am maintaing my sharepoint 2013 server on another machine since that is the requirement for the installation of OWA but still error is coming.
The following error keeps popping up.I have windows server 2012R2 installed.

[image]

Comment: Does the OWA server have anything installed on it at all other than the OS and patches? Have you been through the pre-requisite installation (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx for details of the PowerShell to run to install the pre-reqs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you have some reference to SharePoint on the server, even if you have removed SharePoint from it. My suggestion is to reinstall Windows Server 2012 R2 from scratch making sure you don't have any reference to SharePoint at all. It's a bit of work, bur it usually pays off to make things right from the start.

I once tried to install SharePoint 2007 on a server which had SharePoint 2010 on it. I uninstalled SharePoint 2010, used Microsoft Fix-It and ended up hacking the registry - all without any luck and two days to waste. Reinstalling solved the issue then.

Comment: SharePoint Designer is also a part of SharePoint and causes this error message.